# Which ffmpeg video codec should I use to create MP4 files compatible with Windows Media Player 12?

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg, video-codecs

How do I determine the appropriate ffmpeg video codec to use in order to create MP4 files compatible with Windows Media Player 12 on Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question to assist anyone else trying to figure this out.  I spent a good deal of time thrashing through online posts until I found out how to have Windows Media Player 12 simply tell you what codecs it supports.

Go to Windows Media Player 12's Help / About / Technical Support Information, it generates a local web page with version information and a section listing the video codecs it supports, including these MP4 decoders:

```
Name                 Format
Mpeg4s Decoder DMO   mp4s, MP4S, m4s2, M4S2, MP4V, mp4v, XVID, xvid, DIVX, DX50
Mpeg4 Decoder DMO    MPG4, mpg4, mp42, MP42
```

Next, run "ffmpeg -codecs" to list all of the codecs it knows about, including:

```
mpeg4      MPEG-4 part 2 (decoders: mpeg4 mpeg4_cuvid ) (encoders: mpeg4 libxvid )
msmpeg4v1  MPEG-4 part 2 Microsoft variant version 1
msmpeg4v2  MPEG-4 part 2 Microsoft variant version 2
msmpeg4v3  MPEG-4 part 2 Microsoft variant version 3 (decoders: msmpeg4 ) (encoders: msmpeg4 )
```

I used the "mpeg4" video codec as follows:

```
ffmpeg.exe -stats -i "my home video.avi" -vcodec mpeg4 -acodec aac -f mp4 "my home video.mp4"
```

and I was able to successfully open "my home video.mp4" in WMP 12.

Comment: Have you tried `H264`? That's the standard. `mpeg4` is decades old and fairly inefficient.

Comment: Yes, I tried H264.  VLC plays it, WMP doesn't.  I also tried installing the HEVC Extensions for Windows 10, made no difference.

Comment: What was your command to try H264?